# How to get a cpu v cpu function for a react game

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I've build a simple rock, paper, scissors game within a react app and I'm trying to create a button that when clicked allows the cpu to play itself (cpu v cpu). Currently the user plays the cpu using the following function:

```
handleMove(playerMove) {
  var cpuMove = this.getCPUMove(), //get the current state of the cpuMove function
    result = this.scoreGame(playerMove, cpuMove) //get the current result from the playerMove and cpuMove functions

  console.log('Player chose: ' + playerMove + '. CPU chose: ' + cpuMove + '.')
  console.log('The winner is ' + (result === 1 ? 'player.' : result === 2 ? 'CPU.' : 'draw.'))

  this.setState((prev,props) => ({
    games: [...prev.games, { player: playerMove, cpu: cpuMove, winner: result }]
  }))
}
```

To get the cpu to play itself I tried the following button command:

```
<button type="button" onClick={ this.handleMove()}><span>Computer v Computer</span></button>
```

But the game end up displaying the error:

[image]

I'm fairly new to learning React. The full code is kept in [this Github repo](https://github.com/tobi-ajala/react-rockpaperscissors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your render function, it shoud be like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleMove(this.getCPUMove()) }><span>Computer v Computer</span></button>
```

Comment: With this the cpu loses every time. Do you know of a way in which to differentiate maybe cpu1 v cpu2?

Comment: Works like a charm once a couple of console log statement edits are made. Thank you!